# Запустить функцию, если meta_value изменен php wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, база-данных, веб-программирование

Я создал бота для вайбер и хочу присылать сообщения, когда статус поста меняется на `"is-exist"`

Код бота (это не весь бот, ведь не хватит места для него всего. Это лишь часть только для одной модели и серии):

```
<?php
require_once( 'wp-load.php' );
require_once("../public_html/vendor/autoload.php");
use Viber\Bot;
use Viber\Api\Sender;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

$status = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'status', true );
$status = urldecode($status);

$make = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'make', true );
$make = urldecode($make);

$serie = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'serie', true );
$serie = urldecode($serie);

$config = require('./config.php');
$apiKey = $config['apiKey'];

// reply name
$botSender = new Sender([
    'name' => 'Badzinger Auto',
    'avatar' => 'https://i.ibb.co/2Y88L4m/viber-2021-04-13-16-35-44.jpg',
]);

// log bot interaction
$log = new Logger('bot');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('/tmp/bot.log'));
try {
    // create bot instance
    $bot = new Bot(['token' => $apiKey]);
    $bot
    
        // first interaction with bot - return "welcome message"
        ->onConversation(function ($event) use ($bot, $botSender, $log) {
            $log->info('onConversation handler');
                                 global $wpdb;
$makes = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'make' ",ARRAY_A);
$makes = $wpdb->get_col( $makes );

            $buttons = [];
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($makes); $i++)  {
                    if ($i != 22 && $i != 24){
                        
                    
                $buttons[] =
                    (new \Viber\Api\Keyboard\Button())
                        ->setColumns(3)
                        ->setActionType('reply')
                        ->setActionBody($i)
                        ->setText(ucfirst ($makes[$i]));
}
}
                                        
            return (new \Viber\Api\Message\Text())
                ->setSender($botSender)
                ->setText("Виберіть марку авто, яке хочете відстежувати")
                ->setKeyboard(
                    (new \Viber\Api\Keyboard())
                        ->setButtons($buttons)
                );
        })
        // when user subscribe to PA
        ->onSubscribe(function ($event) use ($bot, $botSender, $log) {
            $log->info('onSubscribe handler');
            $this->getClient()->sendMessage(
                (new \Viber\Api\Message\Text())
                    ->setSender($botSender)
                    ->setText('Дякуємо за підписку!')
            );
        })
        ->onText('|btn-click|s', function ($event) use ($bot, $botSender, $log) {
            $log->info('Виберіть марку');
            $receiverId = $event->getSender()->getId();
            $bot->getClient()->sendMessage(
                (new \Viber\Api\Message\Text())
                    ->setSender($botSender)
                    ->setReceiver($receiverId)
                    ->setText('Ви відстежуєте')
            );
        })
        ->onText('||', function ($event) use ($bot, $botSender, $log) {
            $caseNumber = $event->getMessage()->getText();
            $log->info('onText demo handler #' . $caseNumber);
            $client = $bot->getClient();
            $receiverId = $event->getSender()->getId();
            switch ($caseNumber) {
                case 0:
                     $client->sendMessage(
                        (new \Viber\Api\Message\Text())
                            ->setSender($botSender)
                            ->setReceiver($receiverId)
                            ->setText('Модель')
                            ->setKeyboard(
                                (new \Viber\Api\Keyboard())
                                    ->setButtons([
                                        (new \Viber\Api\Keyboard\Button())
                                            ->setBgColor('#ffffff')
                                            ->setTextSize('small')
                                            ->setTextHAlign('center')
                                            ->setActionType('reply')
                                            ->setActionBody('Megane')
                                            ->setText('Megane'),

            }

  $caseNumber1 = preg_replace('||', '', $event->getMessage()->getText());
            switch ($caseNumber1) {
                case 'Megane':
                     $client->sendMessage(
                        (new \Viber\Api\Message\Text())
                            ->setSender($botSender)
                            ->setReceiver($receiverId)
                            ->setText('Вы следите за Renault Megane.')

                    );
                    
   function send_message( $link ) {
    global $client, $botSender, $receiverId;

    $client->sendMessage(
        ( new \Viber\Api\Message\Text() )
            ->setSender( $botSender )
            ->setReceiver( $receiverId )
            ->setText( 'Renault Megane with status "Is exist": ' . $link ) );
```

Функция в functions.php:

```
function change_post_meta_action( $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
    if ( ! ( 'status' === $meta_key && 'is-exist' === urldecode( $meta_value ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

  send_message( get_post_permalink( $object_id ) );
}

add_action( 'added_post_meta', 'change_post_meta_action', 10, 4 );
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'change_post_meta_action', 10, 4 );
```

Также я хочу поставить ссылки на эти посты вместо `(links to these posts)`. Искал решения в интернете, но не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Для контроля обновления метаданных поста надо использовать хуки. Вставьте такой код в `functions.php`. Вам надо добавить извлечение id пользователей, отслеживающих Megane, из базы wp. А в код бота - добавление id этих пользователей в базу.

```
<?php

use Viber\Bot;
use Viber\Api\Sender;
use Viber\Api\Message\Text;

/**
 * Fires immediately after meta of a specific type is added.
 * Fires immediately after updating metadata of a specific type.
 *
 * The dynamic portion of the hook, `$meta_type`, refers to the meta object type
 * (post, comment, term, user, or any other type with an associated meta table).
 *
 * @param int    $meta_id    ID of updated metadata entry.
 * @param int    $object_id  ID of the object metadata is for.
 * @param string $meta_key   Metadata key.
 * @param mixed  $meta_value Metadata value. Serialized if non-scalar.
 */
function change_post_meta_action( $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
    if ( ! ( 'status' === $meta_key && 'is-exist' === urldecode( $meta_value ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    send_message( get_post_permalink( $object_id ) );
}

add_action( 'added_post_meta', 'change_post_meta_action', 10, 4 );
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'change_post_meta_action', 10, 4 );

function send_message( $link ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . '../public_html/vendor/autoload.php';

    $config = require ABSPATH . 'config.php';
    $apiKey = $config['apiKey'];

    // Reply name.
    $botSender = new Sender(
        [
            'name'   => 'Badzinger Auto',
            'avatar' => 'https://i.ibb.co/2Y88L4m/viber-2021-04-13-16-35-44.jpg',
        ]
    );

    // Create bot instance.
    $bot = new Bot( [ 'token' => $apiKey ] );

    $client = $bot->getClient();

    // Get receiver ids from database.
    $receiverIds = [];

    foreach ( $receiverIds as $receiverId ) {
        $client->sendMessage(
            ( new Text() )
                ->setSender( $botSender )
                ->setReceiver( $receiverId )
                ->setText( 'Renault Megane with status "Is exist": ' . $link ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: То есть мне нужно первый код вставить в functions.php?

Comment: Я вставил первый код в functions.php (как и другие хуки), но ничего не происходит при изменении статуса (Название статуса правильное, я его использовал для других функций) и если я вставляю первый код в файл бота, то результат такой же. Я не вставлял часть кода с `@param`, ведь это комментарии. Нужно ли его вставлять и почему не работает функция? Если я удалю функцию и оставлю сообщение без условие, то оно придет, то есть дело не в этом.

Comment: Я не знаю, где у вас код `$client->sendMessage` и не могу за вас правильно написать, как его  вызвать. Покажите код бота для Вайбер, которого вы создали. Я вам дал код, который срабатывает в нужный момент и находит постоянную ссылку поста.

Comment: Комментарии с @param и проч можно не копировать. Они здесь для того, чтобы показать правильный стиль оформления кода.

Comment: Я добавил часть кода с ботом (только для Renault Megane).

Comment: Бот у вас вне WordPress, работает асинхронно, по событиям. Надо отправить сообщение конкретно тем пользователям, что отслеживают  Megane. У вас коде никак не сохраняются их id. В ваш бот надо добавить сохранения id тех пользователей, что отслеживают Megane, а в мой код - извлечение этих id из базы.